# AES Encryption | InvalidCipherTextException: MAC check in GCM failed, while decrypting the cipher text at c# side

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, fips, aes-gcm

I am stuck while decrypting a cipher text (at C# side) which was encrypted using Microsoft's BCRYPT.h at c++ side. I am getting exception saying Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: MAC check in GCM failed.

As far as I know it is related to MACTag mismatch or any other parameter mismatch. I have verified that I am using the same values but still it is not working.

Below is the flow I am using:

1. Encrypting the text using BCryptEncrypt function of BCRYPT.h at c++ side.
2. using the same key, iv and aad at c# side.
3. At c# end I am using bc-fips-1.0.2.dll to decrypt.

Please find the below Code which I am using:

At C++ Side ( I have formatted the lines in bold which are used as data at c# side)

```
void Encrypt()
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithmAes = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKeyAes = NULL;
    ULONG cbKeyObjectLength = 0;
    ULONG ulWritten = 0;
    UCHAR* pbKeyObjectAes = 0;
    UCHAR  iv[12] = { 0 };
    UCHAR tag[16] = { 0 };

    NTSTATUS status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
        &hAlgorithmAes,
        BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM,
        NULL, 0
    );

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to get algorithm provider for AES..status : %08x\n", status);
        //goto cleanup;
    }

    status = BCryptSetProperty(
        hAlgorithmAes,
        BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE,
        (BYTE*)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM,
        sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM),
        0
    );

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("Failed to set property for AES..status : %08x\n", status);
        //goto cleanup;
    }

    BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTHS_STRUCT authTagLengths;
    status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlgorithmAes, BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH, (BYTE*)&authTagLengths, sizeof(authTagLengths), &ulWritten, 0);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
    {

    }

    DWORD blockLength = 0;
    status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlgorithmAes, BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH, (BYTE*)&blockLength, sizeof(blockLength), &ulWritten, 0);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
    {

    }

    const std::vector<BYTE> keyAes = MakeRandomBytes(blockLength);
    
    **std::string keyUsedAtCSharpSide = base64_encode_new(&keyAes[0], keyAes.size());**

    status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlgorithmAes, &hKeyAes, 0, 0, (PUCHAR)&keyAes[0], keyAes.size(), 0);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
    {

    }
    const size_t GCM_NONCE_SIZE = 12;
    const std::vector<BYTE> origNonce = MakeRandomBytes(GCM_NONCE_SIZE);
    **std::string ivNonceUsedAtCSharpSide = base64_encode_new(&origNonce[0], origNonce.size());**
    BYTE origData2[] = "test";
    DWORD origDataSize2 = sizeof(origData2);
    const std::vector<BYTE> origData = MakePatternBytes(18);

    // Encrypt data as a whole
    PBYTE encrypted = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, blockLength);

    std::vector<BYTE> authTag(authTagLengths.dwMinLength);
    {
        BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
        BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);
        authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)&origNonce[0];
        authInfo.cbNonce = origNonce.size();
        authInfo.pbTag = &authTag[0];
        authInfo.cbTag = authTag.size();
        
        status = BCryptEncrypt
        (
            hKeyAes,
            // &encrypted[0], encrypted.size(),
            origData2, origDataSize2,
            &authInfo,
            0, 0,
            &encrypted[0], blockLength,
            &ulWritten, 0
        );
    }
    **std::string tagIdUsedAtCSharpSide = base64_encode_new(&authTag[0], authTag.size());**
    **std::string encryptedStringUsedAtCSharpSide = base64_encode_new(encrypted, blockLength);**
}
```

**At C# Side:**

```
private static byte[] AesDecrypt()
        {
//Below Data is taken from the c++ side and hardcoded here
              byte[]  aesKey = Convert.FromBase64String("KSO+hOFs1q5SkEnx8bvp6w==");
              byte[]  iv = Convert.FromBase64String("s6bbPIcMPpkkXg0c");
              byte[]  encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String("q/KR75wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==");
            int macBitSize = 96;
            byte[] decryptedMessage = null;
            try
            {
                CryptoServicesRegistrar.SetApprovedOnlyMode(true);
                var key = new FipsAes.Key(aesKey);
                IAeadCipherService cipherService = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService(key);
                var algorithmDetails = FipsAes.Gcm.WithIV(iv).WithMacSize(macBitSize);
                IAeadCipherBuilder<IParameters<FipsAlgorithm>> aeadDecryptorBuilder = cipherService.CreateAeadDecryptorBuilder(algorithmDetails);

                var decryptor = aeadDecryptorBuilder.BuildAeadCipher(AeadUsage.AAD_FIRST, new MemoryInputStream(encryptedData));
                
//Below Data is taken from the c++ side and hardcoded here
                byte[] aadAuthData =Convert.FromBase64String("HX0BeEQNYbrpjA23");// Strings.ToByteArray( This message was sent 29th Feb at 11.00am - does not repeat");
                decryptor.AadStream.Write(aadAuthData, 0, aadAuthData.Length);
                /**/
                using (var stream = decryptor.Stream)
                {
                    decryptedMessage = Streams.ReadAll(stream);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            return decryptedMessage;
        }
```

Please guide me to resolve this error.

Comment: On the C++ side (1) you aren't passing (and don't even have) any AAD (2) you are treating the ciphertext in `encrypted` as having length `blockLength` (which is 16) but it is actually `ulWritten` (which is the same as the plaintext length, 5). On the C#/Bouncy side you don't have or use the tag-aka-MAC, which from the userguide I found on their website it appears should be appended to the (real) ciphertext to form the decryption input

Comment: for (1) - As far as I am aware if we are not providing aad GCM algorithm will generate it and give it as an output which I used in c# side.
for(2) - Yes this might be the problem but I tried with length 5 as well, at c# side it is giving "data is too short" exception

I am not able to understand about your comment from BouncyCastle side as same algorithm is working fine if both client and server are written using C#.
decryptor.AadStream.Write(aadAuthData, 0, aadAuthData.Length); line is used to add authentication data to stream. @dave_thompson_085

Comment: You are using the AuthTag from c++ side as AAD at C# side, As seen from the code AAD is not used during encryption so no need to append AAD during Decrypt method.

Secondly you need append encrypted output and authTag together before sending it for decryption. (enc output bytes + authtag bytes)

These are the major loose point in your algorithm, some minor points which I found out during debugging has been mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are minor mistakes in your implementation which may be due to lack of documentation reading and non-standard way of Algorithm Outputs. I have debugged your code snippet and find below loose points which I think are common while working on cross platform and multiple algorithm implementation:

1. Microsoft's BCrypt implementation of AES-GCM doesn't provide tag and encrypted data all together (unlike in BouncyCastle it is appended with the encrpted output itself.)

**pbTag** parameter will have the Authentication Tag. (*authTag* in your case)

**pbOutput** parameter will have the encrypted data. (*encrypted* in your case)

2. For AeadUsage.AAD_FIRST in BC lib, you should have your decryptiong input in below format: **(auth Tag must be in the end of encrypted data)**

> Encrypted Data bytes + Auth Tag Bytes

You can do something like below at c# end (or similar thing can be done at c++ side itself).

```
var tag = Convert.FromBase64String("YadCQ6V4c3nOUdniqlzymw ==");
encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String("q/KR7/U=");
byte[] data = new byte[tag.Length + encryptedData.Length];
encryptedData.CopyTo(data, 0);
tag.CopyTo(data, encryptedData.Length);
```

3.As indicated by @dave_thompson_85 in comment use **pbResult** ( *ulWritten* in your case) parameter i.e. number of bytes encrypted to take the encrypted bytes.

```
`base64_encode_new(encrypted, ulWritten);`
```

4. using `BYTE origData2[] = "test";` will add an extra \0 in the byte error which will cause the Tag Mismatch. Update it to something else(like below) and make sure about this at any other place.

   `std::string origData2("test");`
5. You are confused with AAD and AuthTag, please learn about those. if you have not specified the AAD during encryption you should not specify it during decryption as well. Remove the below two lines from AesDecrypt method.

```
byte[] aadAuthData =Convert.FromBase64String("HX0BeEQNYbrpjA23");// Strings.ToByteArray("This message was sent 29th Feb at 11.00am - does not repeat");
decryptor.AadStream.Write(aadAuthData, 0, aadAuthData.Length);
```

**Additionally**
If you wish to use your own AAD, then during encryption you have to assign the pbAuthData, cbAuthData parameters in BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO structure. (and same AAD should be added at BC side.)

Comment: Thanks you insights, 
After correcting all above I have get it decrypted at c# side. 
I have also tried with my aad, with that as well it is working now.